# Is it possible to separate the variables in this ODE without a substitution?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-{\frac{4x}{y}}-\frac{y}{x}.
$$

I want to separate it to solve for $y$.

I could do it by using the substitution $v=\dfrac{y}{x}$, separating $v$ and $x$, solve for $v$, then doing the inverse substitution $v$.

But is there a way to solve this without a substitution?

Comment: I do not believe so, but you could multiply by $2y$ and then let $v = y^2$ and then can use integrating factor and that might be slightly easier.

Answer (score 7):

Multiply by $y$ and you have
$$
yy'=-4x-\frac{y^2}{x},
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{2}(y^2)'=-4x-\frac{y^2}{x}, \tag{$\star$}
$$
which is a linear equation, with unknown function $z=y^2$.

In particular, multiplying $(\star)$ by $2x^2$ we obtain
$$
x^2(y^2)'=-8x^3-2xy^2,
$$
or
$$
x^2(y^2)'+2xy^2=-8x^3,
$$
or
$$
(x^2y^2)'=-8x^3
$$
or
$$
x^2y^2=-2x^4+c
$$
or
$$
y^2=-2x^2+\frac{c}{x^2}.
$$

Comment: @user2943324: See updated version.